# How would I go about making a magic item from a Least Warlock Invocation?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, warlock

I have a vested interest in getting Wild Empathy without anything from class or race, the added bonus of being able to speak to animals is pretty handy as well.  What would be the cost for a custom magic item or something of that nature to use the Least Warlock Invocation *Call of the Beast*?  I would prefer this as a constant item but lesser would be useful to know so I can work up to it or something if I must.

EDIT: For clarification, this question was posted as an effort to get Wild Empathy on a character who is *not* a Warlock, and will never be a Warlock.  I was asking for methods to gain it without taking levels in any particular class, or having any specific race.  So basically, Magic Items or something else that can be taken by anyone (such as feats that don't require casting or spellcaster level or something).  Sorry if the way I worded it caused any confusion.

Comment: There's a table for estimating the cost of custom magic items here: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm, any reason this wouldn't be enough to eyeball it? Especially comparing the invocation to a spell level and using that as a basis seems like it'd get you pretty close.

Comment: I could probably get pretty close to it but I was wondering if there was something in regards to Warlocks or Invocations in particular, guessing at this point there isn't but I wasn't sure if anyone else had encountered something.

Answer (score 3):

[Creating Magic Items](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm) will offer you the guidance. [Call of the Beast](http://eberronunlimited.wikidot.com/invocation:call-of-the-beast) (2<sup>nd</sup>) would require [Craft Wondrous Item](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#craftWondrousItem) and that feat requires caster level 3<sup>rd</sup>. One small hurdle will be *Estimating Magic Item Gold Piece Values* which is explained below:

CL 3<sup>rd</sup> x SL 2<sup>nd</sup> x 2000 gp / 2 (for 24 hour effect) = 6,000 gp.

It would take 6 days to craft, cost you raw materials up to 3,000 gp, and cost you 240 xp. Not too shabby, however, why not just take the invocation and spend nothing? It lasts all day...

---

Clarification regarding balance

Building the magic item this way is superior, simply because it would make the magic item cheaper. The invocation essentially combines two different spells. A magic item mimicking two different abilities would have to combine two different spell effects which would probably double the price.

Comment: I'll leave it open for now but it's looking like this is as good an answer as I'm gonna get unless there are rules specifically for Warlocks/Invocations for magic item creation stuff (which I honestly doubt, but someone might have come across them)

Comment: @Dorian Warlocks make good crafters due to emulating. Two levels of the Chameleon prestige class will allow you to change a bonus feat every day, which could be a different crafting feat. At level 12, the Warlock can replicate any spell to make whatever magic item he has the feats for.

Comment: I know that, but I'm not trying to make it myself, I want it made for a character I have who is not a Warlock.  I just wasn't sure if there's any rules for crafting with their Invocations is all.

Comment: @Dorian Artificers can create any magic item they want.

Answer (score 0):

There are no specifications in the RAW regarding to creating a magical item from a Warlock Invocation. According to the Warlock:

> A warlock’s invocations are spell-like abilities

As they are distinctly different from Spells (Evidenced by the different feats EG: Quicken Spell-Like Ability), I would not allow items to be crafted using an Invocation. This is entirely up to your ruling, as I don't believe there is a ruling in RAW.  I've including details for the Warlock's Invocation as well.

[Speak with Animals](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/speakWithAnimals.htm) is a 1st Level Druid Spell, which gives the following benefit:

> You can comprehend and communicate with animals. You are able to ask questions of and receive answers from animals, although the spell doesn't make them any more friendly or cooperative than normal.

As Wild Empathy typically allows you to perform a Diplomacy check without being able to understand the target - I would allow anyone under the effect of Speak with Animals to attempt a Diplomacy Check without requiring Wild Empathy.  You can use the following details to craft an item providing this benefit.

Under the rules for [Item Creation](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm), a continuous item has the following rules.

> Spell level × caster level × 2,000 gp<sup>3</sup>
>
> 3. If a continuous item has an effect based on a spell with a duration measured in rounds, multiply the cost by 4. If the duration of the spell is 1 minute/level, multiply the cost by 2, and if the duration is 10 minutes/level, multiply the cost by 1.5. If the spell has a 24-hour duration or greater, divide the cost in half.

The minimum level required for the feat [Craft Wondrous Item](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#craftWondrousItem) is 3.  According to the magical Crafting rules however:

> A creator can create an item at a lower caster level than her own, but never lower than the minimum level needed to cast the needed spell.

Thus as you can cast Speak with Animals at Level 1, this is the Caster Level of the item.

Based on this information, we can calculate the lowest possible cost of the item as follows.

```
 Spell level = 1
Caster Level = 1
    Duration = Mins
 Calculated  = 1 x 1 x 2 x 2000GP
  Total Cost = 4000GP
```

Using the same details for a warlock's invocation ends at an item slightly cheaper:

```
 Spell level = 2
Caster Level = 1
    Duration = 24 Hrs
 Calculated  = 2 x 1 x 2000GP \ 2
  Total Cost = 2000GP
```

Comment: Call of the Beast is a 24 hour effect and equivalent to a 2nd level spell.

Comment: Can you explain why Speak with Animals item would require CL3? It is 4k gp worth, I believe (1 x 1 x 2k x 2).

Comment: @annoyingimp it would require a caster of 3rd level or higher to create the wondrous item.  Though you could create it at a lower caster level still.

Answer (score 0):

## Ask the DM about Magic Items that Grant Feats

A character may, if the DM permits, be able to acquire the least invocation *call of the beast* (*Complete Mage* 123) using the *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* (which remains legal in *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*) *Arms and Equipment Guide* rules for Magic Items that Grant Feats, which says, in part, that

> A general guideline for [determining the market price of] other kinds of [items that grant] feats is that they cost 10,000 gp, plus another 5,000 gp to 10,000 gp per prerequisite.

Thus a magic item granting the feat Extra Invocation (*Complete Arcane* 79) would, by this estimate, cost between 15,000 gp and 20,000 go because of the feat's prerequisite. The item's final cost, the item's prerequisites, and—most importantly for our purposes—whether the wearer of such an item must still *meet* the feat's prerequisite are up to the DM.

### Gaining the effects of the invocation *call of the beast*

I only found one item that granted an at-will effect like the spell [*speak with animals*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/speakWithAnimals.htm) [div] (*PH* 221), and that's the *circlet of the wilderness* (*Unapproachable East* 56) (50,000 gp; 0 lbs.), which grants the ranger that wears it a host of spell-like abilities, making reverse-engineering the author's evaluation of that specific effect practically impossible.

I *hate* Table 7–33: Estimating Magic Item Gold Piece Values (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 285), but without further guidance, it gives at least a starting point. Using the table to compute the price of a continuous 1st-level *speak with animals* effect yields a market price for such an item of 4,000 gp.<sup>1</sup>

Computing the price of a magic item granting the extraordinary ability [wild empathy](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#wildEmpathy) (*PH* 35) requires some Dumpster-diving. The *mantle of rage* (["New Magic Items"](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/MagicItems.pdf) 2) (6,000 gp; 1 lb.) grants any creature that wears it the extraordinary ability rage 1/day as if the creature were a level 1 barbarian. I think for most campaigns that's a reasonable comparison and a reasonable price.

Were I DMing, I'd probably allow a player whose character possesses the feat Craft Wondrous Item to create a custom magic item (say, *helm of the beast*?) that grants a continuous *speak with animals* effect and the ability to use wild empathy as if a druid for a market price of 10,000 gp. In a campaign wherein such abilities are particularly useful (e.g. animals everywhere have long memories and incredible observational skills just no language, hiveminded penguins as primary opposition, [*The Herculoids*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Herculoids), *Jurassic Realms*), I might as much as double the item's price, but I'd still keep in mind the cost of that *circlet of the woodlands*.

I'd probably make the prerequisites the extraordinary ability wild empathy as well as the spell *speak with animals* so the character'd have to work alongside a smelly druid for a week or three. Because that's funny.

---

<sup>1</sup> 2,000 gp base price ×1 for caster level 1st ×1 for spell level 1st ×2 for a spell duration normally of 1 min. per level.

Comment: The _Call of the Beast_ invocation is considered the equivalent of a second level spell, and though it grants an extraordinary ability it also lumps it with the _Speak with Animals_ effect.  In addition it has a 24 hour duration.  I wasn't sure if there were particular rules for magic item creation for duplicating the effects of Invocations otherwise I'd have just gone straight to the table myself with that and the minimum caster level requirement for the Craft Wondrous Items feat.  Please see the edit I made to the question.

Comment: Regarding the usefulness of such abilities, it is perfectly reasonable to charge extra for it.  This campaign wasn't one where that was expected to be incredibly useful, I merely wanted it for character flavor.  The first encounter we had was against wolves, and on a whim I decided to have the character walk up and pet one of the wolves, and the DM let me make a Performance check to influence attitude since I didn't have Wild Empathy and couldn't use Diplomacy.

Comment: @Dorian While the invocation is equivalent to a 2nd-level spell, the effects are equivalent to a continuous 1st-level spell and a 1st-level class feature, and that's the method that should be used when creating a new magic item using Table 7–33. I will, however, make it clear that the first item, with DM permission, is perfectly acceptable for a non-warlock.